# Recursive neural network implementation in TensorFlow

Tags: natural-language, tensorflow, recursive-model

Is there any available recursive neural network implementation in TensorFlow TensorFlow's [tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/index.html) do not present any recursive neural networks. Most TensorFlow code I've found is CNN, LSTM, GRU, vanilla recurrent neural networks or MLP. I am most interested in implementations for natural language processing.

[Example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/158995/12359) of a recursive neural network:

[image]

The tree structure may vary between different inputs. I.e., I do not want the tree structure to be fixed.

Comment: I was looking for something similar, if you're open to using theano instead of tensorflow you could have a look https://github.com/ofirnachum/tree_rnn. There are a few examples on display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Tensorflow Fold:

https://github.com/tensorflow/fold

TensorFlow Fold is a library for creating TensorFlow models that consume structured data, where the structure of the computation graph depends on the structure of the input data.

Answer (score 0):

These types of architectures are awkward in Tensorflow. I think someone did implement them though. http://www.kdnuggets.com/2016/06/recursive-neural-networks-tensorflow.html

You might prefer to use DyNet, which was designed to allow for dynamically changing architectures. https://github.com/clab/dynet

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you need:
https://github.com/sapruash/RecursiveNN:

> Tensorflow implementation of Recursive Neural Networks using LSTM units as described in "Improved Semantic Representations From Tree-Structured Long Short-Term Memory Networks" by Kai Sheng Tai, Richard Socher, and Christopher D. Manning.

Comment: You need to explain your answer and not just give a link that you think may be applicable.

Comment: This is rather a comment. Can someone convert this answer to a comment?

Comment: I have added some information, it qualifies as an answer in my opinion. Is that okay for you Ferdi and Michael Chernick?